# Help identify this SMD (diode) component

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I could use some help identifying the component in the picture. It is marked T2N, but I have no idea about the specifications. It is from a 1993 Lexus LS400 engine ECU, these are known for their leaking capacitors. This SMD component was mounted near a leaking capacitor and the leads / soldering pads were affected. Now I need to replace it, but I'm not sure which component I should order. If anyone could help, it would be greatly appreciated! (the photo shows the same parts on the back side of the circuit board)[image]

Comment: Nothing on [yooneed](https://smd.yooneed.one/code5432.html), likely custom-made.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different diode parts with similar numbers, without the manufacturer ID (the broken cathode line is a clue if someone recognizes it) and the case size are likely required. It's probably T2 + lot number or something of that ilk.

However, there is nothing bad that a leaking capacitor is going to do to a  plastic packaged diode. Just clean it off. Even if the pads/leads are eroded due to errant current flowing through spilled electrolyte there should still be plenty enough to repair.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason I need to replace this component is that the leads were corroded (and broken) by the electrolyte. It just fell off when I touched it.